# Wrong real_ip header in nginx logs

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, okd

I deployed nginx pod in OKD 4.8.
The problem is that the IP showing in the logs corresponds to the VM where ingress-controller is running.

This is the config for my passthrough OKD route:

```
  - kind: Route
    apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: app-cname
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      host: "app.dev.com"
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: app
        weight: 100
      port:
        targetPort: 8080-tcp
      tls:
        termination: passthrough
        insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
```

This is my current config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
        error_log /dev/stderr;
        pid /run/nginx.pid;
        worker_processes auto;
        include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
        events {
            worker_connections 1024;
        }
        http {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
            log_format  main  '$remote_addr forwarded for $http_x_real_ip - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                              '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                              '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
            map $http_user_agent $logme {
                default            1;
                ~^kube-probe*      0; # do not log user-agent for ocp readiness probe
            }
            access_log /dev/stdout main if=$logme;
            sendfile            on;
            tcp_nopush          on;
            tcp_nodelay         on;
            keepalive_timeout   65;
            types_hash_max_size 2048;

            include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            default_type        application/octet-stream;
        
            # Allow up to 10 MiB payload, app defaults to 10 MiB.
            client_max_body_size 10M;

            include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

            server {
                listen 8080 ssl; 
                listen [::]:8080 ssl;

                root /var/www/html;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;

                ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/app.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/app.key;

                ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
                ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
                ssl_session_timeout 10m;
                ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
                ssl_session_tickets off;
                ssl_stapling on;
                ssl_stapling_verify on;

                resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s; # check with igor
                resolver_timeout 5s; # check with igor

                add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;

                add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

                ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
                ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;

                add_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy require-corp;
                add_header Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy same-origin;
                add_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy same-origin;
                add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
                add_header X-Frame-Options deny;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

                location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
                }

                location ~ \.(php|phar)(/.*)?$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.(?:php|phar))(/.*)$;
                    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                    fastcgi_index  index.php;
                    include        fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;

                    fastcgi_hide_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy;
                    fastcgi_hide_header Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy;
                    fastcgi_hide_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy;
                    fastcgi_hide_header Referrer-Policy;
                    fastcgi_hide_header X-Content-Type-Options;
                    fastcgi_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
                    fastcgi_hide_header X-XSS-Protection;

                    # Prevent exposing nginx + version to $_SERVER
                    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE "";
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there anything that does not make sense?

This is my setup:

```
sh-4.4$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.14.1
built by gcc 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 FIPS  11 Sep 2018 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,-Wl,-E'
```

How can I display the real original IP in nginx logs?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to OKD4 - but when using passthrough, the tcp stream will be transfered without tempering and the source ip is the one of the OpenShift routers.

If you want to have the x-forwarded-for, you will have to change it to "reencrypt" instead - but then of course the SSL will be terminated on the routers and a new https session will be opened - if you don't need the end-to-end encryption, that is fine (but will add load to the cluster, of course).

Comment: end-to-end encryption is a requirement for me :(, what you say is true, tried using "edge" and X-Forwarded-For header showed up. But, when using "passthrough" X-Forwarded-For header is unset.

Comment: That there is no X-Forwarded-For header when using "passthrough" is what you want when defining "passthrough". When defining passthrough you expecitely tell the system not to change anything but take the TCP package and send it as is to the backend. But of course the source ip will be that of the new sender (your haproxy).

Nothing to do there ...